# How is float_of_int -3 evaluated?

Tags: ocaml

```
# float_of_int -3;;
Error: This expression has type int -> float
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

I thought function application has the highest precedence, so `float_of_int -3` is equal to `float_of_int (-3)`. Why do I need to put the parentheses explicitly there to suppress the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly because of this reason, that function application is having higher precedence than infix operators, you have to add parenthesis.

In other words, function application is greedy and it will consume all terms until it reaches an infix operator, e.g.,

```
 f x y z + g p q r
```

is parsed as `(f x y z) + (g p q r)`.

The same is with your example,

```
 float_of_int - 3
```

is parsed as

```
(float_of_int) - (3)
```

Another option for you would be to use a special prefix operator `~-`, e.g.,

```
float_of_int ~-1
```

which has [higher precedence](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec133) (binds tighter) than the function application.